# Can you please help me in deleting a registry folder?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, regedit

I need to delete this folder
{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}

From the location HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\C
urrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace

So, anyone please help me with the commands so that i can make a .reg file to delete the folder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove OneDrive?  [Just hide it from within File Explorer instead](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/remove-onedrive-file-explorer-sidebar-windows-10/) removal of the key won’t remove OneDrive.  I cannot recommend the removal of that key.

Comment: Why do yoou want a .reg file instead of just opening Regedit and deleting it? This feels like it might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I dont use one drive Ramhound. By the way, how did you know it was ondrive.

Comment: EBgreen. Using a .reg file will be more easier in the future, right. Thats why :)

Comment: Gronostaj i am not stuck. I know how to access regedit and delete it manually. But dont know how to create commands for deleting it with a .reg file.

Comment: @JustinThomas - I am smart.  I know stuff.  If you don’t want to give the necessary background to help you that’s your prerogative

Comment: I have no idea if that is right or not. For instance if you are in a corporate environment I would say that a GPO would be a better solution. A script in SCCM would be more maintainable IMO as well. Regardless if you don't want to provide background information that is your perogative.

Comment: Ramhound, I know removal of the key wont remove onedrive. I have uninstalled it. And also hidden it. But there is this one more place where the onedrive shows up and the only way to hide it is to delete the above specified folder. So if anyone knew the commands to delete a folder inside a folder in regedit, that would be helpful.

Comment: If i have to do the same in 100 computers it would be easy to have a .reg file other than locating the folder right. Thats why :)

Comment: Except that if you have to do 100 computers GPO is generally a better method or a scripted solution through a configuration management tool like SCCM or Altiris or even AppSense is generally a more maintainable method.

Comment: Regardless, the magic that you are looking for to do it with a reg file is `-`

Comment: I got an answer EBGreen :)

Comment: @JustinThomas - If you have to perform this task on a 100 different machines, you have not identified the correct thing to do, because this registry key would exist for every single user on each of those 100 machines.  After you removed the key, you did perform a restart, otherwise it woudln't work.

Answer (score 5):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}]
```

Though it maybe even easier to do this in a `Command Prompt` open as admin:

> reg delete
>   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}
>   /f

Comment: Both methods are not working.

Comment: @JustinThomas - You asked us how to delete the registry file by creating a .reg file.  The instructions in this answer, indicate how to do that, if it's not working you need to provide more information other then "it's not working" by editing your question.

Comment: I meant that the reg file created by using this methods havent deleted the key folder. The key foldrer is still there after the execution.

Comment: @JustinThomas Did you run it as a admin or the batch file as admin some parts of the registry are read-only otherwise.

Comment: Yes, i did run it as administrator. Anyways, i'll do it manually itself. Thank you :)

Comment: @JustinThomas That is weird because I tested it on my PC and it worked.

Comment: It worked? May be, i am doing something wrong then. I have also tried to create a test folder and changed the commands as Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{test}] and extecuted it. Still the folder was there.

Comment: How did you execute it?

Comment: Right click and run as administrator of course.

Comment: www.howtogeek.com/225973/how-to-disable-onedrive-and-remove-it-from-file-explorer-on-windows-10 The howtogeek guy has added the reg tool (.reg file) to remove/hide onedrive showing up on our windows explorer. But he missed one place where onedrive shows up.

Comment: Anyways i'll remove the onedrive manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer - Modifying the registry without having some understanding of it can result in serious damage to your PC. I would recommend doing some reading up on it, or at the very least doing a system backup. If you still want to delete a folder do so at your own risk!

1. Open regedit. From run prompt `win +r` type regedit and hit enter.
2. In the left pane navigate to the path you specified. Either just
   follow the folder structure or paste in the path in to the nav bar
   above.
3. Right click on the desired folder and delete [image: Registry editor]

Edit - to delete a key with a `.reg` file add a hyphen before the path to the key

e.g. Something like this should do the trick

`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}]`

Comment: I want to help you avoid down votes for trying to help so I will point out that the OP explicitly does not want to delete using the GUI.

Comment: Gytis, That didn't help. But thank you for your time in helping a rookie :)